# Appending an array with a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to write a function to append an array with a for loop. The data I'm trying to append is in a JSON repsonse. However, I keep getting x10 `Array[]` in the web console instead of one array with all the data. When I run `console.log(dates[0])` I get returned in the web console `"undefined"`. This tells me the data isn't even making it into the array. When I run `console.log(time)` I return x10 peices of data from the JSON I want but of course its not in the array. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
function mostRecent(time) {
    var dates=[];
    for (var i = 0; i < time.length; i++) {
        dates.push(dates[i]);
    }
    return console.log(dates);
    }
```

Comment: It's `dates.push(time[i])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pushing `dates[i]` with every loop cycle. And since `dates` array keeps being empty, you are actually pushing `undefined`.

Just replace `dates.push(dates[i])` with `dates.push(time[i])`.

**Note**: You should return `dates` instead of `console.log`.

Comment: Hmmm...I'm still receiving 10 undefined repeats in the console when I return console.log(dates[0]).

Comment: @prime90 Just return `dates` instead of console.log